# Validate null values inside object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have two keys in an object. I am checking the below three scenarios

- if statusUrl value is having some value, then success
- if statusUrl value is "", errorUrl value must not be ""
- if both statusUrl and errorUrl are empty, then failure

I am using below working code, but want to know if there is any better approrach to do this in a more simpler way.

```
var obj = {
    statusUrl: "",
    errorUrl: ""
};
function validate(key) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || obj[key] === "") {
        return 1;
    }
}
var flag = validate("statusUrl");
if (flag) {
    var result = validate("errorUrl") ? "failure" : "success";
}
console.log(result)
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tu9m9oc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this

```js
var obj = {
  statusUrl: "",
  errorUrl: ""
};

function validateObject(obj) {
    return (obj.statusUrl != "" || (obj.statusUrl == "" && obj.errorUrl != ""));
}

var result = validateObject(obj) ? "success" : "failure";

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To summarize your requirement, either statusUrl or errorUrl have value mean success, else mean failure. How about

```
var obj = {
  statusUrl: "", errorUrl: ""
};
var result = (obj.statusUrl || obj.errorUrl) ? "success": "failure";
console.log(result)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j09Lynma/

Comment: **if statusUrl value is "", errorUrl value must not be ""** - If `statusUrl` is empty and `errorUrl` is not then `success`

Comment: @Weedoze Did you try out my code before you down vote it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  statusUrl: "",
  errorUrl: ""
};

var result = "failure";

if (obj.statusUrl) {
  result = 'success';
} else {
  if (obj.errorUrl) {
    result = 'success';
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "simpler" way

```
var obj = {
    statusUrl: "",
    errorUrl: ""
  },
  result = validate(obj);

console.log(result);

function validate(obj){
  if (obj.statusUrl !== "") { 
    //1. if statusUrl value is having some value, then success
    return "success" 
  } else if(obj.errorUrl !== "") { 
    //2. if statusUrl value is "", errorUrl value must not be ""
    return "success" 
  } else { 
    //3. if both statusUrl and errorUrl are empty, then failure
    return "failure" 
  }
}
```

Careful when checking against `truthy/falsey` values.

```
var a = "0",
    b = 0;

console.log(!a); //false
console.log(!b); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var obj = {
  statusUrl: "",
  errorUrl: ""
};

function validate(obj) {
    if (obj.statusUrl != "" || (obj.statusUrl != "" && obj.errorUrl != "") || (obj.statusUrl == "" && obj.errorUrl != "")) {
        return 1;
    }
}

var output = validate(obj) ? "success" : "failure";

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
var result=(obj.statusUrl && obj.statusUrl!=""?"success":(obj.errorUrl && obj.errorUrl!=""?"success":"failure"))

console.log(result)
```